# how to display both prev/next button when hover img in cycle2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle2

I want to display both the prev/next button when hover image in `cycle2.js`.

This is the link for your reference http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/prevnext.php

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
data-cycle-timeout=0
>
<!-- prev/next links -->
<div class="cycle-prev"></div>
<div class="cycle-next"></div>
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use position: relative on the cycle-slideshow, and position: absolute on the buttons. I'd suggest you to try it first and come back if you need further help.

Comment: What do you mean by positioning? I just want to display both next/prev button when i hover image. Because if you open the link and hover the image it displays one button only.

Comment: I think I misunderstood it, got it now, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(function () {
    $(".cycle-prev, .cycle-next").css("opacity", "0");

    $(".cycle-slideshow").hover(function () {
        $(".cycle-prev, .cycle-next").css("opacity", ".7");
    }, function () {
        $(".cycle-prev, .cycle-next").css("opacity", "0");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem now is i have 3 slideshow on my page. When i hover the slideshow1 the buttons on the slideshow2 and slideshow3 are displaying too. I want the buttons only display when hover its respective slideshow.

Comment: Its okay now i just put ID per div. Thank you so much for your help sdcr.